# Spring boot getting java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set

Tags: spring, spring-boot, castor

I am using Spring boot 2.1.1.RELEASE and castor 1.2. It starts fine, works as expected for few hours and then suddenly it starts getting the below error -

```
o.c.c.u.Configuration                    : Failed to load configuration from classpath: /org/castor/core/castor.core.properties
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
        at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:435)
        at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
        at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
        at org.castor.core.util.Configuration.loadFromClassPath(Configuration.java:187)
        at org.castor.core.util.Configuration.loadDefaultProperties(Configuration.java:136)
        at org.castor.core.CoreConfiguration.<init>(CoreConfiguration.java:49)
        at org.castor.xml.XMLConfiguration.newInstance(XMLConfiguration.java:58)
        at org.castor.xml.AbstractInternalContext.<init>(AbstractInternalContext.java:121)
        at org.castor.xml.BackwardCompatibilityContext.<init>(BackwardCompatibilityContext.java:45)
        at org.exolab.castor.xml.Unmarshaller.<init>(Unmarshaller.java:206)
```

The jar is present inside BOOT-INF\lib\castor-1.2.jar\

Do we need to place /org/castor/core/castor.core.properties somewhere in the classpath to resolve this issue? Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Normally there should be a default properties file. As the manual says on https://castor-data-binding.github.io/castor/reference-guide/reference/xml/xml-properties.html you can provide that file in the classpath.

Comment: The issue here is it is not happening all the time, after running successfully for few hours it starts getting this error. Then after restarting the spring boot it again starts working. The application is running in a linux m/c. Can it be because of high volume of requests, or cache/space issues?

Comment: @Developer did you find any solution to this? I'm also stuck on this problem